# Trying to echo a foreach to send via php in html

Tags: php, email, foreach, cart

Hi there so i'm doing a shopping cart and I do print an array with foreach on my website, after that the customer need to fill in their shipping information and send the form. But when I want to send the for each through email with php mail I keep getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in end.php on line 189" Any help on this one?

Code : http://pastebin.com/mv0QY4tZ - Related line in between 169-310

Comment: Can we see something?

Comment: So you got a syntax-error. You should probably fix that, but we can't help you without seeing some code. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y7UvZkbu There you go - This is the confirmation page

Comment: @Zonta That's *a lot* of code.. Post the relevant part of it here in your question instead.

Comment: @Qirel if you have control over that pastebin's expiry; do so. Otherwise, your paste won't be any good after that 13 days.

Comment: Sorry for that -  Code for my question is in between line 169-310

Comment: make up a new pastebin link and embedded in your question and don't give it an expiry date

Comment: Line 189 should be `</div>'; foreach( $desc as $j => $code ) {`

Comment: There you got I added the pastebin

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh no, I don't have control of that. Not my question, not my code :-) I don't even know which part of that big chunk is relevant to OPs question, because he even censored the line of the error.

Comment: @Qirel *duh!!!*, sorry about that, *lol* I mispinged. When the @ came up and I thought I had started typing a "Z" and may have accidentally pressed "Q" instead. I'll blame it on my (mild) case of dyslexia and "short term memory loss". ;-) edit: Or I wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: @Zonta Please post the *relevant* code **in the question itself**; linking to the code on Pastebin isn't a substitute for posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot echo into a string your assigning($message02). Close the string out first. Then run your foreach that creates a combines string. Then combine the strings at end all together.

on line 190.
      ';

```
 </div>';

$message02partb = "";
foreach( $desc as $j => $code ) {
    if ($qte[$j] <= 9) {
        $spacer[$j] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
   $message02partb = $message02partb . '<div class="row row-2"><div     class="coffee-span-6 column-5">' . $code . '</div><div class="coffee-span-2">    <a href="http://www.laptopliquidation.org/lab/cart/cart.php?sub=1&id='.$j.'"><img src="./img/bilang/sup.png" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $qte[$j] . $spacer[$j] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.laptopliquidation.org/lab/cart/cart.php?add=1&id='.$j.'"><img src="./img/bilang/add.png" /></a></div><div class="coffee-span-2 column-6" style="text-align: right;">' . $price[$j] . '</div><div class="coffee-span-2"  style="text-align: right;">' . $price[$j]*$qte[$j] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.laptopliquidation.org/lab/cart/cart.php?del='.$j.'"><img src="./img/bilang/rem.png" /></a></div></div>' ;
   $stWithoutLiv += $price[$j]*$qte[$j];
   if ($multipleBB[$j] == 1 && $qte[$j] >=1 ) {
        $boxin[$j] = ceil($qte[$j]/$limitPBox[$j]);
       $numberBox[$j] += $boxin[$j];
       $priceShip[$j] += $costLiv[$j]*$boxin[$j]+($qte[$j]-    $boxin[$j])*$costLivMul[$j];
   }

}

$message02partc = '<div class="row row-3">
    <div class="coffee-span-12 column-7"></div>
```

Then combine them all at end near line 281

```
     <br /><br /><br /><br />';

$message02 = $message02.$message02partb.$message03partc';

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y7UvZkbu There you go - This is the confirmation page

Comment: Sorry for that -  Code for my question is in between line 169-310

Comment: @ Line 201  vous ne avez pas besoin un '.' apres le foreach et avant <div>

Comment: @useyourillusiontoo Not working with the "." still Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in /home/laptopli/public_html/lab/cart/end.php on line 189 and Steven Eveyting look closed

Comment: @useyourillusiontoo I mean without the "."

Comment: Did you replace Line 189 with this:  
</div>';
 foreach( $desc as $j => $code ) {

Comment: Steven thank you! This solved my problem